# Use spark-api in java,on yarnclient mode,container:tomcat8,error:FileNotFoundException:__spark_libs__*.zip

Tags: tomcat, apache-spark

When I use spark-api for java, execute job from web, on the yarnclient mode, this is the tomcat logs exception:

```
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://dev1:8088/cluster/app/application_1495078972652_0002Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: File file:/usr/local/tomcat/temp/spark-aae1afc9-5738-4e5b-ae29-f8935adf53b8/__spark_libs__1867469074993542381.zip does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/usr/local/tomcat/temp/spark-aae1afc9-5738-4e5b-ae29-f8935adf53b8/__spark_libs__1867469074993542381.zip does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
```

My code:

```
private void initSparkConf(String appName) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client").setAppName(appName);
        conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize","2g") ;
        this.context = new JavaSparkContext(conf) ;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date start = new Date() ;
        Utils.taskStart("Test Spark",start);
        SparkTest model = new SparkTest("test") ;
        testWorkCount(model.getContext());
        model.getContext().close();
        Utils.taskEnd("Test Spark",start,new Date());
    }

/**
* word count test
* @param context JavaSparkContext
*/
private static void testWorkCount(JavaSparkContext context) {
        JavaRDD<String> lines = context.textFile("hdfs://192.168.1.110:9000/east3/JYLS/JYLS-20150520.txt");
        JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(",")).iterator());
        JavaPairRDD<String,Integer> pairRDD = words.mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2<>(word,1)) ;
        JavaPairRDD<String,Integer> countRDD = pairRDD.reduceByKey((count1,count2) -> count1+count2) ;
        countRDD.coalesce(1,true).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://192.168.1.110:9000/east3//result/" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date()));
    }
```

spark-env.sh:

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=dev1
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/usr/local/spark/local_dirs
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_CLASSPATH:${SPARK_HOME}/lib/
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES=3
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES=2
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=1G
export SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=2G
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/scala
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=dev1  
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8090  
export SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT=8099  
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=8g
```

spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.master                                    spark://dev1:7077
spark.eventLog.enabled                          true
spark.eventLog.dir                              hdfs://dev1:9000/spark/eventlogs
spark.serializer                                org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.executor.memory                           2g
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions                 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"
```

Tomcat run on the master node .

Why the file **spark_libs***.zip exists only on master node in a cluster?
Why worker node find the file from "tomcat temp" dir ?
How can i resolve this exception ?

---

**Thanks.**